# MySql select top 3 results from each country

Tags: mysql

Here be my problem ... (very grateful for any advice from the MySql experts out there)

I have a database table specifying:
time (9.99, 10.96, 11.02 etc..)
country (eg JAM, USA, CAN ect..)
date (eg. 2011, 2012, 2013 etc..)

I wish to display a ranking list ordered by time (ASC) for a specified year (2012)

The catch - I only want to show a maximum of three entries per country and the list must be ordered by time (ASC)

I have tried (from another suggestion on here):

```
set @num := 0, @country := '';
select country, time
from (
select country, time,
  @num := if(@country = country, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
  @country := country as dummy
from stats

where eventID = 1
order by country
) as x where x.row_number <= 3;
```

However, this works to a degree - but it orders the list by country (alphabetical).

Apologies if this is to vague .. but would love some ideas!!!

many thanks in advance!

Comment: So ORDER BY something else !?!?! Still struggling? Consider posting up proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: in your example `time` is a decimal value? `9.99, 10.96, 11.02` what do these values mean? I see you have the year saved in the date-column, but what does time contain exactly? Is this a combined day-of-the-month-daytime-value of some kind? just curious

Comment: Sorry guys, pretty new to this ... here is the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc5a9/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @n=0,@s=-1;
SELECT
    country,
    time
FROM (
    SELECT
        country,
        time,
        @n:=IF(@s=-1 OR @s=country,@n+1,1) as n,
        @s:=country
    FROM
        stats
    ORDER BY
        country
) as tmp
WHERE
    n <= 3
ORDER BY
    time
```

Comment: Thanks - that's almost there! I have set up this sqlfiddle for a better idea of what I am trying to achieve http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc5a9/1 Fastest to slowest on time - no more than three results per country

Comment: @GavinLovegrove glad to hear it :) do not forget to accept the answer so that others can see the solution